# How to avoid overhead to pass a Map[Integer, String] where a Map[Number, String] is expected?

Tags: performance, scala, collections, types, dictionary

The problem:
I have a mutable.Map[Integer, String], I want to pass it to two methods:

1. def processNumbers(nums: Map[Number, String])
2. def processIntegers(nums: mutable.Map[Integer, String])

after getting compile error, I ended up with this:

```
val ints: mutable.Map[Integer, String] = mutable.Map.empty[Integer, String]
//init of ints
val nums: Map[Number, String] = ints.toMap[Number, String]
processNumbers(nums)
processIntegers(ints)
```

With a little experiment, I figured out that my way of doing this has a significant overhead: the type conversion step multiply by 10 the execution time.
All in all the type conversion is really just to please the compiler, so how to do that without any overhead ?

For info, the code of my experiment:

```
package qndTests
import scala.collection.mutable
object TypeTest {
  var hashNums = 0
  var hashIntegers = 0
  def processNumbers(nums: Map[Number, String]): Unit = {
  nums.foreach(num =>{
      hashNums+=num._1.hashCode+num._2.hashCode
    })
  }
  def processNumbers2(nums: mutable.Map[Integer, String]): Unit = {
  nums.foreach(num =>{
      hashNums+=num._1.hashCode+num._2.hashCode
    })
  }
  def processIntegers(nums: mutable.Map[Integer, String]): Unit = {
  nums.foreach(num =>{
      hashIntegers+=num._1.hashCode+num._2.hashCode
    })
  }
  def test(ints: mutable.Map[Integer, String], convertType: Boolean): Unit = {
  if(convertType)
    println("run test with type conversion")
  else
    println("run test without type conversion")

  val start = System.nanoTime
  hashNums = 0
  hashIntegers = 0
  val nTest = 10
  for(i <- 0 to nTest) {
    if(convertType){
      val nums: Map[Number, String] = ints.toMap[Number, String] //how much does that cost ?
      processNumbers(nums)
    }else{
      processNumbers2(ints)
    }

    processIntegers(ints)
  }
  val end= System.nanoTime
  println("nums: "+hashNums)
  println("ints: "+hashIntegers)
  println(end-start)
}
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val ints: mutable.Map[Integer, String] = mutable.Map.empty[Integer, String]
  val testSize = 1000000

  println("creating a map of "+testSize+" elements")
  for(i <- 0 to testSize) ints.put(i, i.toBinaryString)
  println("done")

  test(ints, false)
  test(ints, true)
  }
}
```

and its output:

creating a map of 1000000 elements
done
run test without type conversion
nums: -1650117013
ints: -1650117013
2097538520
run test with type conversion
nums: -1650117013
ints: -1650117013
25423803480

--> about 2 seconds in the first case against 25 seconds in the second one !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've seen, `Map[A,B]` is nonvariant in the key type `A`, so you'll need a conversion of some kind to assign to a variable of type `Map[A,B]` a `Map[A1,B]` where `A1 <: A`. However, if you can change the definition of `def processNumbers(nums: Map[Number, String])`, you could try something like:

```
def processNumbers[T <: Number](nums: Map[T, String])
```

and pass the `Map[Integer, String]` without conversion.

Would that help solve your problem?

Comment: Works great, thanks :-) Can we do another trick in case we cannot change the definition of processNumbers (if it comes from a library)?

Comment: @acapola Not that I know of. In case you're really concerned about performance and you really know that the library is actually treating it as a `Map[Int, String]` even if it is badly designed and requires a `Map[Number, String]`, then you *could* consider casting your map: `ints.asInstanceOf[Map[Number, String]]`, but in general it's a **very bad idea** and just begs for a `ClassCastException` to happen somewhere later.